# What is causing this error "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

1.
I have this method in my repository class

```
public class VariablesRepository : IVariablesRepository
    {
         readonly DBContextClass _context = DBContextClass.Current;
         public Variables Find(string name)
         {
           return _context.Variables.FirstOrDefault(c =>   c.Name.ToLower().Equals(name.ToLower())) ?? new Variables();
         }
    }
```

2.
I also have this static class

```
public class Defaults {
        private static VariablesRepository _variablesRepository;
        static Defaults() {
            _variablesRepository = new VariablesRepository();
        }
    public class MOSScheduleTypes
    {
       private static int _tryValue;

       public static readonly int OneTime = int.TryParse(_variablesRepository.Find("MOSScheduleTypes.OneTime").Value, out _tryValue)
                                                       ? _tryValue
                                                       : 1;
    }
}
```

3.
Now if i do this somewhere in code: for example

```
if(someValue == Defaults.MOSScheduleTypes.OneTime) 
{ 
  //some code here.... 
}
```

I get the error : The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed

Comment: Where are you instantiating `_variablesRepository`?

Comment: MOSScheduleTypes is a class inside a class called Defaults. The Defaults class has the _variablesRepository instantiation

Comment: Do you mind updating your question with that info? Even if I can't help, someone else might find that info useful.

Comment: What does `DbContextClass.Current` do?  Please include that too.

Comment: 1. I have updated code. 2.The DbContextClass.currrent gets the current DbContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved this issue by using raw ado.net code, so i just changed the find method from entity framework linq code to raw ado.net data access code. 
The error didn't occur any more, if anyone has a better solution using entity framework, please share. The find method rewritten, code below:

```
public Variables Find(string name)
        {
            var objVariable = new Variables();

            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringValue"].ToString()))
            {
                conn.Open();

                var sql = @" select top 1 * 
                            from SomeTable 
                            where Column1 = @Name";

                try
                {
                    var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = name;

                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        if (dr.Read())
                        {
                            objVariable.Column1 = dr["Column1"].ToString();
                            objVariable.Column2 = dr["Column2"].ToString();
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                }
            }

            return objVariable;

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by the data context being disposed.  As you haven't shown any code for disposing of...anything, it means that there is some code somewhere else that is disposing of that same data context.

Note that data contexts are designed to be short lived; it's code smell to see you holding onto the data context as you are for later use, particularly in a static variable that appears to be long lived.

Instead of grabbing the current data context once you should be grabbing it right when you need it.  Since you won't be storing the data context as an instance field of `VariablesRepository`, the method can also be made static (it will have no instance data to use).

```
public class VariablesRepository : IVariablesRepository
{
     public static Variables Find(string name)
     {
       return DBContextClass.Current.Variables.FirstOrDefault(c =>   c.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) ?? new Variables();
     }
}

public class Defaults
{
    public class MOSScheduleTypes
    {
        private static int _tryValue;

        public static readonly int OneTime = int.TryParse(VariablesRepository.Find("MOSScheduleTypes.OneTime").Value, out _tryValue)
                                                        ? _tryValue
                                                        : 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that your LINQ query is deferred, in other words it is not run in your "VariablesRepository" but only in the calling code. So the DBContext has already been disposed of when it is executed. You can force it to execute immediately by adding .ToList() so changing

```
return _context.Variables.FirstOrDefault(c =>   c.Name.ToLower().Equals(name.ToLower())) ?? new Variables();
```

to

```
return _context.Variables.ToList().FirstOrDefault(c =>   c.Name.ToLower().Equals(name.ToLower())) ?? new Variables();
```